# Docker - dotnet restore fails connection to private feeds

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

Calling `dotnet restore <project>` from my Dockerfile is resulting in a `NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source` error.  I've been going through many of the suggested similar questions and continue to have issues.  Here is as much info about the things I've tried as I can provide:

- Docker Engine has its DNS set to "8.8.8.8"
- Using Linux containers
- `RUN ping google.com` succeeds (so I can reach the internet)
- Works perfectly fine hitting the `nuget.org` feed
- The nuget.config file currently has credentials in it just to get this working

  - This will be removed for a different approach once I get this working
  - These are the same credentials (username/PAT) that I use during development on my host machine
- `RUN curl <nuget_feed_url>` succeeds
- Running the restore command with `--verbosity detailed` doesn't provide any other error messages but the one

Here is the section of the Dockerfile in question

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.13 AS base
# Create dockeruser in base layer
RUN addgroup --system --gid 1000 dockergroup \
    && adduser --system --uid 1000 --ingroup dockergroup --shell /bin/sh dockeruser

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
# Arguments are required in each stage in order to get the correct value

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/Nucleus.LumberYard.API/", "Nucleus.LumberYard.API/"]
COPY ["./nuget.config", "./nuget.config"]

WORKDIR "/src/Nucleus.LumberYard.API"
#COPY [".editorconfig", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "Nucleus.LumberYard.API.csproj"
RUN dotnet build "Nucleus.LumberYard.API.csproj" -c Release --no-restore
```

Environment info

- Docker Desktop v3.3.1
- Docker v20.10.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on my understanding you have the following scenario:

- a .NET 6 application with some references to nuget packages
- some nuget packages are taken from the usual Nuget public repository, some others are taken from a private nuget feed
- you are distributing your application via a docker image and during the docker build process you want to run a `dotnet restore` command targeting one of your `csproj` file
- the `dotnet restore` command fails because the `dotnet` cli is unable to talk with your private nuget feed

I encountered the very same situation with the project I'm working on. We have a private Nuget feed hosted in Azure Devops and we too had some troubles figuring out how to solve this.

First of all, let's clarify the root cause of the problem.
You did the right thing veryfying that you are able to reach the nuget feed from your build machine, via the `curl` command you mentioned.
What is actually failing is the authentication between your build machine and the private nuget feed.

The first thing you need is a personal access token **with read permissions** for your nuget feed. You can follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows#create-a-pat) to create the personal access token you need.

Once you have the token, you need to provide it to the `dotnet` cli.
There are several ways to do so, I'm going to explain the one that worked for us.

Instead of adding the nuget source to the `nuget.config` file, we registers it via a cli command.
I'm quite sure there is a way to do **exactly the same thing** via the `nuget.config` file (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesourcecredentials) for more details).

This is the cli command we use inside of our docker file:

```
RUN dotnet nuget add source https://foo.bar.com/something/nuget/v3/index.json -u "whatever" -p "my-personal-access-token" --store-password-in-clear-text --valid-authentication-types "basic"
```

Notice that:

- `https://foo.bar.com/something/nuget/v3/index.json` is the absolute URL pointing to the index of your private nuget feed
- the username can be whatever you like. You **do** need to provide a value, but I didn't notice any difference even putting there a random string like `whatever`
- the fictious value `my-personal-access-token` must be substituted with the personal access token you have created as a first step

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-add-source) you can find the full reference for the `dotnet nuget add source` command.

After registering this source with the `dotnet` cli, you will be able to run your `dotnet restore` command with no errors.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This got me one step closer it feels like.  I didn't even think to use `dotnet nuget add source` and after doing that (before the restore) I'm still getting the same error but now it doesn't error out right away.  It takes ~25 seconds before I get the same error.  I made sure to copy/paste the command, PAT, and source URL just so I wouldn't introduce a typo.

Comment: What happens if you try to do the same thing from your local machine ? I mean, registering the nuget source with the very same PAT. If you then try to run a dotnet restore, does it work ?

Comment: I added the NuGet source through the CLI using the same command you provided and my PAT on my local machine.  Then went to the project I'm trying to restore and it restored it without issue (I made sure to clear my nuget cache beforehand).  So far it's just with trying to build the image from my Dockerfile where it fails.

Comment: I forgot one important detail. Do NOT use both the nuget.config and the cli command. If you use the cli command, you don't need the nuget.config. Have you tried to delete or docker ignore the nuget.config file ?

Comment: I suggest another test on localhost. Can you try to build the docker image on your local computer ? I mean trying a docker build on your machine instead of using the build server.

Comment: Unfortunately all of this has been from my local machine with Docker Desktop.  I also tried removing the `COPY` command for copying `nuget.config` and removed it from the `RUN dotnet restore` command and I still get the same error.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, did you hardcode the PAT value in the docker file ? or are you trying to inject it as a build argument? If this is the case, try to hardcode the PAT value in the docker file and try again to see if it works

Comment: I did hardcode it.  The container environment and my local machine when doing the best I can do have similar scenarios are behaving differently.  I need to try and get some commonality between them first I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251456/discussion-between-enrico-massone-and-logan-k).

Comment: The PAT I was copying/pasting was encrypted and I didn't realize it until I regenerated a new one.  Your suggestion worked perfectly.  Thank you!